# Makefile. Create program with header file

Tags: c, struct, makefile, header-files

I have problem with compliled my program via Makefile. Ofcorse I read many topic with similar problem but I can't understood dependes in my case, so therefore I Have problem with compiling.

Here is my program his was writed on c. Is simply. This is not all content but I suppose that is sufficient to understood problem in Makefile. Program have only 3 files:

- main.c   (include struct.h and use Object from struct.c)
- struct.h
- struct.c (include struct.h)

**main.c**

```
#include "struct.h"
#define SIZE_STRUCT 2  
int main()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 2) 
            {

                printf("Contens %d /n" , CommandStructure[i].size)
                i = i +1;
            }

                return 0;
    }
```

And **struct.h**

```
#ifndef STRUCT
#define STRUCT


struct Command
{   char tableCmd[5];
    char *NameCommand;
    int size;

};

#endif
```

and **struct.c**

```
#include "struct.h"

static struct Command CommandStructure[]={
    {
        .tableCmd = {0x3,0x5,0x4,0x4,0x5},
        .NameCommand = "SOMEWHERE",
        .size = 11,
    },{
        .tableCmd = {0x6, 0x34, 0x40, 0x22, 0x4},
        .NameCommand = "SOMETHING",
        .size = 12,
    }
};
```

**And my main Problem Makefile**

```
NAME=test

all: main.c struct.c struct.h
    gcc struct.c main.c -o $(HOME)/Pulpit/$(NAME)
```

Ofcorse i get error

> error: ‘CommandStructure’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>            if(!strncmp(buf , CommandStructure[i].NameCommand , CommandStructure[i].size))                           main.c:140:27:
>   note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once  for each
>   function it appears in Makefile:6: polecenia dla obiektu 'all' nie
>   powiodły się make: *** [all] Error1

Comment: You never define CommandStructure in main.c

Comment: @bmargulies its' in struct.c file, no?

Comment: to @OP, do you know you're missing `stdio.h`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggested makefile contents:

```
CC := /bin/gcc
RM := /bin/rm

CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -ggdb
LFLAGS :=


NAME := test

OBJS := main.o struct.o

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(NAME) $(OBJS)

%.o: %.c struct.h
<tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -I.

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
<tab>$(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)

clean:
<tab>$(RM) -f *.o
<tab>$(RM) -f %(NAME)

Note: use a tab char where I have used <tab>
```

regarding the struct.c file

using 'static' makes the CommandStructure[] only visible in that file.

Suggest remove the 'static' modifier

regarding the struct.h file

insert the following line so main.c can access the struct

```
extern struct Command CommandStruct[]
```

regarding the main.c file

insert the following line for proper prototypes of printf()

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Suggest learning about the 'for' statement as that would be better than the 'while'  and 'i = i+1;' statements

When indenting the code, always use spaces, not tabs.
because each editor/wordprocessor will have the tab stops/tab width set for personal preference

For readability, suggest indent 4 spaces after each opening brace '{'
and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Answer (score 3):

Declarations in `struct.c` are not visible to `main.c`. You need to declare `CommandStructure` in `struct.h` like so:

```
#ifndef STRUCT
#define STRUCT


struct Command
{   char tableCmd[5];
    char *NameCommand;
    int size;

};

extern struct Command CommandStructure[];

#endif
```

Further, the usage of `static` in `struct.c` does precisely the opposite - it makes sure that the symbol `CommandStructure` is only available in that translation unit. So you should also remove the `static` qualifier from `struct.c`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the `CommandStructure` variable visible from all the translation unit. For that, declare the structure as `extern` in the header file.

Also, you have to remove the `static` storage-class-specifier from `CommandStructure`in `struct.c` file.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. This is it. Rightly must be add one detail **[]** or

```
#ifndef STRUCT
#define STRUCT


struct Command
{   char tableCmd[5];
    char *NameCommand;
    int size;

};

extern struct Command CommandStructure[]; // CommandStructure is table so should be []

#endif
```

I also changed Makefile to this

```
NAME=test

all: 
    gcc struct.c main.c -o $(HOME)/Pulpit/$(NAME)
```

And evrythings is compiled without any error. So, this is not was been problem with Makefile but syntax c file.

Thank You